# Dubai airport transit - electronic cigarettes

Tags: dubai, smoking

I'll be transferring through Dubai on my way to Asia.
I have read conflicting reports about the legality of electronic cigarettes, confiscations etc.

Has anyone got any experience? Would it be best putting it into a checked bag without batteries?

When you're transiting through do you have to go through security again or if it was in my carry on would nobody see it?

Flight is DUB-DXB-BKK with emirates.

EDIT:

I contacted Emirates and they said it would be fine to bring in carry on provided I don't use it in the airport.

Both times in Dubai there was no mention of it by security and there were people in the smoking lounges vaping.

Comment: You will go through security including bag x-ray and body scanner when you make a connection at Dubai airport.

Answer (score 3):

[OP here:] For others wondering: I contacted Emirates and they said it would be fine to bring in carry on provided I don't use it in the airport.

Both times in Dubai there was no mention of it by security and there were people in the smoking lounges vaping.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a chance of nicotine to be present in them, sadly, they are banned. Here is a discussion I have found on [trip advisor](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g295424-i872-k6599306-o10-Electronic_Cigarettes_illegal-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html). They will confiscate it if they find them in your hand luggage. Checked bag without batteries would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

i spoke with the live chat at the dubai website. The conversation went as follows:

Tracy: Hi. Thanks for connecting to Dubai Airports! How can we assist you today?
Visitor12157939: Hi, i was traveling from the UK to asia, transiting in between in dubai
Visitor12157939: i have a vape pen as a gift. Just wanted to know whether this would be a problem for someone who is just transiting for an hour
Tracy: Please give me a moment, while I check for the possible information.
Visitor12157939: sure
Tracy: Please be advised that electronic smoking devices are prohibited in the UAE, all arriving and departing passengers are restricted to possess the same.
Tracy: However, please be informed that it is permissible to carry the item (e-cigarette) in hand baggage if you are a transit passenger.
Tracy: If there's anything you need my assistance with, please do not hesitate to let me know.
Visitor12157939: Thank you so much for you help Tracy